# Youtube Data v3 not working properly

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

The youtube likes/subscriptions appear in the user account, but  not in the video/channel

I'm making a webpage where people accepts youtube permissions (using manage youtube account scope) and they can like videos or subscribe to channels through the web.

With likes:

```
- the user see that has liked the video
- noone never sees the total likes going up
```

With subscriptions the issue is:

```
- at the beginning the user can see he is subscribed to the channel
- after few hours everyone can see the increased number of subscribers
- some time later (like one day or more), the subscribers decreased
- but the user can still see that is subscribed
```

Here is an image of how the user sees it after one day or more: [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrCV0.png)

The code I'm using for likes is:

```
<?php
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();

$client_id= $_POST['client'];
$client_secret= $_POST['secret'];
$refreshtoken = $_POST['ref'];
$idvideo = $_POST['idvideo'];

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$client->refreshToken($refreshtoken );
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
        die('The session state did not match.');
    }
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    try {
        $youtube->videos->rate($idvideo, "like");
        // It always arrives here

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //
    }

    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
    // If the user has not authorized the application, start the OAuth 2.0 flow.
    $state = mt_rand();
    $client->setState($state);
    $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
?>
```

And for subscriptions is basically the same, the only difference is in this if:

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
            try {    
                $resourceId = new Google_Service_YouTube_ResourceId();
                $resourceId->setChannelId($idChannel);
                $resourceId->setKind('youtube#channel');

                $subscriptionSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_SubscriptionSnippet();
                $subscriptionSnippet->setResourceId($resourceId);

                $subscription = new Google_Service_YouTube_Subscription();
                $subscription->setSnippet($subscriptionSnippet);

                $subscriptionResponse = $youtube->subscriptions->insert('id,snippet', $subscription, array());

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                    //
            }
            $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
```

I don't know if google sees my webpage as something strange or what the problem is, but i've been in this same point for aboout one week and haven't find any similar problem.

Also the webpage doesn't appear as blacklisted on www.blacklistalert.org or mxtoolbox.com